# Declaring non-intrinsic types with () after variable name has different behavior than without. i.e. std::map<int,char>x(); - what's with that?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a member variable declaration of:
`std::map<int,char>x;`
in my header file.
It compiles, but when I run my binary I get a segfault in the initialization of the class, before I even get into the constructor.
If I change the declaration to `std::map<int,char>x();` -i.e. I just added a () after the variable name - it works fine, no segfault.

I can't give any more specific example than the above, but if anyone has experience with this I'd be interested to know what's going on.

Compiler version is gcc version 4.8.5
target is x86_64-redhat-linux

I realize this is fairly nonspecific but I'm only looking for a general answer.

Thanks.

Comment: `std::map<int,char>x();` is not a variable. It's a function declaration. *"works fine, no segfault"* Because simply declaring a function without using it does nothing. Try actually using it as a variable, and you'll get another error.

Comment: Can't reproduce: https://godbolt.org/z/m0TsS4 - Need more code, like a [mcve].

Comment: Look up "The most vexing parse" for further.

Comment: "_I have a member variable declaration of: `std::map<int,char>x;` in my header file. It compiles, but when I run my binary I get a segfault in the initialization of the class, before I even get into the constructor._" - Don't you think it would be a good idea to show what the class looks like? How does it do member initialization etc.?

Comment: Thanks folks, I realize it's kind of a garbage example, but I'm unable to provide more detail.  I also think it's a function declaration.  I'll look up the most vexing parse, thank you all.  I'll mark something as accepted as soon as I figure out how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the [most vexing parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse), as coined by Scott Meyers.

In the standard, look up Ambiguity resolution [[stmt.ambig]](http://eel.is/c++draft/stmt.ambig).

As for the segfault, you will need to provide the code (see [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)) to help you with that.